# Find out on which type a static method was called

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class `A` with a static method, and a derived class `B`. You can call `Foo()`, declared in `A`, on both `A` and `B`:

```
public class A
{
    public static void Foo() 
    {
       // How to get typeof(B) here if Foo called by using class B? 
    }
}

public class B : A
{
}

...

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B.Foo();
    }
}
```

Now inside `Foo()`, how can I find out on which type `Foo()` was called?

I can't use keyword `this`, because I do not create any objects here. I have tried already:

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

and

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType
```

but they both return me the `typeof(A)`, while I need to get the `typeof(B)`.

Comment: Have you tried using stacktrace?

Comment: You can't, basically.

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre, Stacktrace looks like a "dirty trick", so I did not try it yet.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thank you!

Comment: The stack trace wouldn't make any difference, as despite the wording of the question, this isn't about the *caller* (which is `Program.Main`), it's about the target class of the static method invocation.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need to find out on which type a static method was called?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I have a lot of "B" classes inherited from the common parent A. B classes have some attributes and my static method should analyze this attributes using reflection for each B class and return some info. Yes, I can make a parameter in the static method and use it for example like this: A.Foo(typeof(B)); A.Foo(typeof(C)); and so on, but B.Foo() is easier to read and write. This is not a big problem in my code. I asked this question to understand the situation in general.

Comment: Jon Skeet and CodeCaster helped me to understand this situation and the answer to my question is simple: you can't. We could close this topic. What should I do: post an answer to the topic by myself or just leave it?

Comment: I'm trying to find the relevant part of the C# spec, but can't find it. The problem is that `B.Foo()` gets compiled to `A.Foo()`, but I can't find any source for why that happens. So feel free to post a self-answer stating you can't do this.

Comment: Check this http://rextester.com/EYEHF53987

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, and agree with the comments that perhaps you can approach this a different way. Saying this, could you do what you need with a generic base class?

```
public class AB<T>
{
    public static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}

public class A : AB<A> { }

public class B : AB<B> { }

A.Foo(); // A
B.Foo(); // B
```

Comment: So create a wrapper class just for pointing out on which type you want to call a static method? Note that static methods can't implement interfaces, so you can't call `T.Foo()` inside your `Foo()`.

Comment: Adding a Type parameter is much cleaner than enforcing a generic class.

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to obtain typeof(B) inside of static method Foo() in this case. The possible solution is to use parameters in Foo method.

Thanks to @Jon Skeet and @CodeCaster.